# how to check for a Letter in J2ME from a char

Tags: java, java-me

how to check for a Letter in J2ME from a char

IN J2SE we can use 
Character.isLetter(c)

I want to use this :
     `if (Character.isLetter(c) && Character.isUpperCase(c)){}`
and also `else if(Character.isSpace(c))`

IN JAVA MOBILE Platform
Any way to use it??

Comment: Are you sure you can't use it?

Comment: Character is the wrapper class for char. And  'isLetter()' is a method to check if the given character is a letter.      J2ME does not support it. need a manual method to do the work of isLetter()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seeing as you can't use `Character.isLetter(c)`, I would just emulate its functionally. I would do this by treating the character as a "number" by using its [ASCII value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters).

```
public static boolean isLetter(char c) {
    return (c > 64 && c < 91) || (c > 96 && c < 123);
}

//Not necessary but included anyways
public static boolean isUpperCase(char c) {
    return c > 64 && c < 91;
}

public static boolean isSpace(char c) {
    //Accounts for spaces and other "space-like" characters
    return c == 32 || c == 12 || c == 13 || c == 14;
}
```

Edit: Thank you @Nate for the suggestions/corrections

Comment: CLDC 1.1 / MIDP 2.0 have `isUpperCase()` and `isLowerCase()`, so there's no need to implement those.  Also, your `isUpperCase()` returns `true` if `c` is lower case.  And then, you should be checking `c < 123`, or `c <= 122`. And the J2SE [version of isSpace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isSpace%28char%29) checks for more than just `(char)32`.  There are four other chars that qualify as *space*.